# Need to use modal in a modal Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using $uibmodel in my angular app.
I need to open a new modal in a one modal. bcoz of that i need to inject 
'$uibModal' and  '$uibModalInstance' both, in one of my controller.
that controller looks somewhat like this.
'$uibModal' and  '$uibModalInstance' in one controller

```
baseController.$inject = ['$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance'];

function baseController($uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {

self.ok = function () {
$uibModalInstance.close(self.selected.item);
};

self.cancel = function () {
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

Now the problem is i am getting error in consolle saying

```
Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance
```

I know this is because of injecting '$uibModal' and '$uibModalInstance' both in one controller, but i have to. Bcoz of that error in console i am not able to close the second modal.
tell me if there any way to use'$uibModal' and '$uibModalInstance' both in one controller. I have to keep both of these in one conteroller.

Comment: Did you forget to assign controller to second modal instance? Create a plunker  demo that reproduces this

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this -

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: '../Template/dummy.tpl.html',
    controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.Delete = function () {
            alert('Delete')
        };

        $scope.Cancel = function () {
            alert('Cancel')
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    },
});
```

This is nothing but just bypassing creating a new controller. If you are using strict di mode, I will suggest you to create a variable and put the controller function there and refer it like this.

```
......
 controller: dummyController;
......
var dummyController = function($scope, $uibModalInstance){
 .......

}
```